# Can you get the subclass of a Method that was inherited?

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection, methods

Take a look at this code:

```
public class Main {

    public class A {
        public final void method() {}
    }

    public class B extends A {}

    public static main() {
        try {
            Method method = B.class.getMethod("method");

            //Returns the name of Main$A, but I want Main$B
            System.out.println(method.getDeclaringClass().getName());
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {}
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the class out of an inherited method that I previously have taken from a subclass. The reasoning for this is in my application, I store all methods with a specified annotation by object into a `Set<Method>` and store the object itself in a `Map<Class<?>, Object>` which is to easily invoke the method later.

I understand that it would make sense for `method.getDeclaringClass()` to return `Main$A`, since that's where it was declared, not `Main$B`, but I was just wondering if there was an alternative to solve my problem.

Comment: What problem? You will get the implementation from the sub-class when you have an instance of the sub-class. This is by design.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I think they do a lookup with `B.class`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch My subclass B does not and _cannot_ override the method in A; I will edit the question to reflect this. Say for example, I wanted to store the instance of `B` in the `Map<Class<?>, Object>` by key `Class<B>` and Method `method()` in the `Set<Method>`, as described in my application. This is where the problem lies: Later on, I would attempt to get the class out of `method()` via the `getDeclaringClass()` method, which is now `Class<A>`. I would then proceed to attempt to take the instance out of my map by that class, and get an NPE.

Comment: @Octopod What do you have access to when populating the `Map`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Just the object. In my problem the object happens to contain inherited methods.

Comment: @Octopod Why don't you use `object.getClass()` as the key?

Comment: I do, but the stored method I get from `object`  does not return `object.getClass()` when I run `getDeclaringClass()`. It returns the superclass, a key which does not exist in my map.

Comment: I'm very confused. When you build the `Map`, you have access to an object, potentially of type `B`. Through this, you can get the `Method` and the declaring class `A`. When you do a lookup in the `Map`, what do you have access to?

Comment: When I populate the `Map` and `Set`, I have access to an object and by extension, the methods within. When I take instances out of the `Map`, I only have access to the `Set` of methods. Sorry for making this sound confusing.

Comment: Simply create an object holding the `Method` and the desired `Class`. You may think about the right `hashCode` for that object as [`Method.hashCode` uses only the declaring class and the name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#hashCode()) which performs poorly in a `HashSet` if you have overloaded methods which differ in the parameter types only…

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to reindex the class methods in a way that is incompatible with the java standards. I don't think there is a workaround for this; your code should reflect the way things are structured; i.e. 
populate your map with the class returned by `getDeclaringClass()`.

Comment: I believe that is what they are doing.

Comment: Hmmm, as i understood it, he puts B.class in the map, but the method belongs to the parent class, thus he can't de-reference the map using the result of getDeclaringClass.

Comment: I populated the map by `object.getClass()` as the key , but also the stored instances would have to be in separate keys; let's say classes B, C, and D all extend A; I can't have them all stored under the key `A.class`, as in my application there is an abstract method in my simplified class A that `method()` accesses. Thank you for the answer though.

Comment: You probably need something fancier then, a `Map<Class, Map<Class, Object>>` to store all the subclasses (and their corresponding instances) given a parent class.